# CORS error while upload files with a loop to Moralis IPFS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ipfs, moralis

I have a JS function which uploads files to Morails IPFS:

```js
const ipfsUploadFiles = async (files) => {
    const uploadedFilesIpfsUrls = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        const ipfsFile = new Moralis.File(file.name, file);
        console.debug(ipfsFile);
        await ipfsFile.saveIPFS(); // error happens here
        const ipfsFilePath = ipfsFile.ipfs();
        const fileInfo = { id: i + 1, fileName: file.name, url: ipfsFilePath };
        uploadedFilesIpfsUrls.push(fileInfo);
        console.log(`Successfully uploaded file`, fileInfo);
    }
    return uploadedFilesIpfsUrls;
}
```

The first few files get uploaded successfully, but soon I start to get a CORS exception. (hidden links and server url).
[image: CORS errors]

There are two requests to  the server, preflight succeeds, but then thre real request fails. After that, all request fail.
The uploading file is visible in payload and has a value written in `base64` property. The size of the file is 9.4MB. The request response code is `502`.

I tried to add some delay in the upload function loop, but I got same results.
I also tried to change the site address from `localhost:30000` to `1270.0.0.1:3000` but it's the same. The third thing that I checked was [an article on Morails about CORS](https://moralis.io/moralis-magazine-2-overcome-cors-errors/), but it is not helpfull.
When I wrapped the call into a try-catch, I got this message:

> Error: XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API"

Is there any limitation on the Morails service that is not described?
Sould I just disable cors in my browser?

Used versions:

- Moralis server version: v0.0.385
- Environment: Ganache
- Moralis NPM package (The Moralis JavaScript SDK): 1.11.0 (tried also 0.0.176)
- React Morails NPM package: 1.4.2 (tried also 0.3.11)

Answer (score 0):

Hi it looks to be a general server issue (could be resources related) looking at the last Parse API error, which will happen if the server is not reachable/unresponsive.

You could try adding delays e.g. with setTimeout for each upload (`saveIPFS()`).

If you have more questions or issues with this, please post with more details (including server / dapp URL) on:

Moralis forum: https://forum.moralis.io